# How to convert list to time series in R?

Tags: r

I have imported my text file like this

```
z<-read.table("o8192",header=FALSE,as.is=TRUE);
```

But I encounter problems on the next step

```
spec.mtm(z,nw=4.0, k=7, nFFT="default", taper=c("dpss"))
Warning message:
In spec.mtm(z, nw = 4, k = 7, nFFT = "default", taper = c("dpss")) :
  Time series is not a ts object and deltat is not set. Frequency array and axes may be incorrect.

> head(z)
         V1
1 -938.5499
2 -938.5424
3 -938.5349
4 -938.5236
5 -938.5236
6 -938.5123
```

z has 8192 lines.

How to convert list to ts?

Comment: It may help if you post `str(z)`, then someone can show you how to convert that to a time series. it may be as simple as `ts(z)` if `z` is `numeric`.

Comment: It is quite difficult to help you without knowing the content of your file. Try to add the output of `head(z)`.

Comment: spec.mtm expect `timeSeries` : A time series of equally spaced data,  this can be created by the ts() function where deltat is specified. Citation from `?spec.mtm`

Comment: @PetrMatousu Yes,that's it,works now!